# JQuery в чистый JavaScript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть такой код:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(document.body).click(function() {
                $("div:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow");
            });

        });
    </script>
    <style>
        span {
            color: red;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        div {
            margin: 3px;
            width: 80px;
            display: none;
            height: 80px;
            float: left;
        }

        div#one {
            background: #f00;
        }

        div#two {
            background: #0f0;
        }

        div#three {
            background: #00f;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <span>Click here...</span>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Как сделать такое-же, но только на чистом JavaScript?

Answer (score 8):

Доки:

- [jQuery hidden selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/#hidden1)
- [JavaScript анимация](http://learn.javascript.ru/js-animation)

Итак, всё необходимое у нас есть, можем начать.

---

```
$(document).ready()
```

Заменяется на

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    //....
}, false );
```

---

Ищем первый скрытый div.

```
$("div:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow");
```

Заменяется на

```
/**
 *
 */
var work_div
,   div_list = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

/**
 * ищем первый скрытый див
 */
for(var i=0; i < div_list.length; i++) {
    if(div_list[i].style.display.toLowerCase() == 'none') {
        work_div = div_list[i];
        break;
    }
}

/**
 * если нашли, то запускаем анимацию
 */
if(work_div != undefined) {
    work_div.style.display = 'block';
    work_div.style.opacity = '0';

    animate({
        duration: 1000, // время на анимацию 1000 мс
        step: function(progress) {
            work_div.style.opacity = progress;
        }
    });
}

/**
 * ф-ция анимации
 */
function animate(opts) {
    var start = new Date;
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        // вычислить сколько времени прошло
        var progress = (new Date - start) / opts.duration;
        if (progress > 1) progress = 1;

        // отрисовать анимацию
        opts.step(progress);

        if (progress == 1) clearInterval(timer); // конец :)

    }, opts.delay || 10); // по умолчанию кадр каждые 10мс
}
```

Comment: А зачем так сложно онлоад ловить?
>window.onload = function() { /* code */};

Comment: @dimka3210 такое запуститься после дом реди, и это не эквивалент, тут все правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Давно это было... Как вариант, [можно таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/SVBQe/). Не особо пинайте, т.к. слегка отвык от натива ))

```
var but = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0],
    divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    timer = null;

but.onclick = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
        if(window.getComputedStyle(divs[i], null).getPropertyValue('display') == 'none'){
            animateEl(divs[i]);
            return false;
        }
    }
};

function animateEl(el){
    el.style.display = 'block';
    el.style.opacity = 0;
    clearInterval(timer);
    var opacIncr = 0;
    timer = setInterval(function(){
        el.style.opacity = opacIncr;
        opacIncr += 0.1;
        if(opacIncr >= 1) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    },50);
    return false;
}
```